# How to Select and multiply certain columns based off criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

I am trying to write a code that is dynamic for European countries to capture the appropriate price based on the certain country. I am trying to pull data where the List Price is less than 4000, but wanted to add a statement that if the Currency is in SEK, then I want to multiply that list price by 10 and then if it's less than 4000  I want to include it. For other Currencies just take the list price as is for currency codes EUR, GBP, and CHF.

For example this is what I have and it's not working correctly:

```
SELECT
       [Country_IBS]
      ,[Item_Number]
      ,[Price_List]
      ,List_Price
      ,[Currency]
FROM #temp4

WHERE List_Price < 4000 

OR (SELECT List_Price * 10 WHERE Currency = 'SEK') < 4000
AND Currency = 'EUR'
OR Currency = 'GBP'
OR Currency = 'CHF'
```

Comment: AND is evaluated before OR. You need parentheses. E.g. `AND (Currency = 'EUR'
OR Currency = 'GBP'
OR Currency = 'CHF')`. (That one can also be written as `AND Currency IN ('EUR', 'GBP', 'CHF')`.)

Comment: It helps if you can be more specific than "it's not working correctly". Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
where
    list_price * (case when currency = 'SEK' then 10 else 1 end) < 4000
    and currency in ('EUR', 'GBP', 'CHF', 'SEK')
```

Or you can use the more verbose form:

```
where
    (currency in ('EUR', 'GBP', 'CHF') and list_price < 4000)
    or (currency = 'SEK' and price < 400)
```

Answer (score 0):

`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. You need to club you conditions in parentheses.

Your query should be like this:

```
--version 1: Using OR
SELECT
       [Country_IBS]
      ,[Item_Number]
      ,[Price_List]
      ,List_Price
      ,[Currency]
FROM #temp4
WHERE (List_Price < 4000 AND Currency IN ('EUR','GBP','CHF'))
OR (List_Price * 10 < 4000 AND Currency = 'SEK')

--Version 2: Using UNION ALL
SELECT
       [Country_IBS]
      ,[Item_Number]
      ,[Price_List]
      ,List_Price
      ,[Currency]
FROM #temp4
WHERE List_Price < 4000 AND Currency IN ('EUR','GBP','CHF')

UNION ALL

SELECT
       [Country_IBS]
      ,[Item_Number]
      ,[Price_List]
      ,List_Price
      ,[Currency]
FROM #temp4
WHERE List_Price * 10 < 4000 AND Currency = 'SEK'
```

These queries returning same resultset might have different query plan as per indices created on your table. Use whichever is more efficient than another.

Explore [Operator Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [UNION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more details.